# How much Shannon entropy is there in people voting for Trump?

Tags: entropy, probability, information

What I mean is: a voter choosing Trump or Clinton had a simple binary choice (I'm simplifying by 'forgetting' other candidates). Yet, would it not be unfair to state that all voters' votes contained the same, small, amount of entropy?
After all, much information has gone into forming the final choice for each of them.

ALthough Shannon's theorem may not (from my understanding) take this into account, is there a way to measure this?

An extension of these could be: voters pick delegates, who pick the president, who picks the UN ambassador (or whatever) who makes several yes/no binary decisions.
Yet, would it not be unfair, from the point of view of how much information it contains, to measure each step as containing equal amount of information. Is there a way to discriminate these?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about Game theory/Social choice theory, not about physics.

Comment: Google; Condorcet's jury theorem. It shortly states that highest possible amount of voters provides the most reliable result.

Comment: @Wolpertinger I was more focused on the Shannon entropy bit than Trump. That's just an easy example, but I'd love a general explanation for similar systems. Having said that, if you think Shannon/ information entropy questions fit better elsewhere I'd be happy to hear where.

Comment: @JokelaTurbine thanks very interesting. I guess I am looking for something that measures the difference between those voters. Although ultimately all votes count the same, I wonder if we can measure how much information is in different votes.

Comment: @matteoeoeo I think in theory that all votes count the same, but given candidates propensity to spend time and money in "swing states" (PA, OH, FL...) kinda suggests otherwise :/

Answer (score 1):

Based on what I know about Shannon entropy, it is not really a calculatable quantity in the situation you have described.  I suppose it could be calculated in principle, but certainly not in practice.

The question you have posited does involve a sequence of "choices", and the Shannon entropy of a series of "choices" (or bits) is generally a thing that can be calculated.  However, in order to calculate the Shannon entropy of a series of choices, you have to know the probabilities of making these choices.

It's a bit of a stretch to compare binary "choices" with bit strings, but I think I see the overall gist of your question.  To explain a little further, we can calculate the Shannon entropy of a bit string such as:

> 1011 0011 0111 1001 1000 0010 1000

provided that we know the probabilities of 1s and 0s appearing in each position.

However, in the situation you have described, we don't know the probabilities of the binary choices that are being made.  I suppose we could make wild conjecture about "what is the probability of a delegate choosing such-and-such", but any Shannon entropy you calculate would only be as good as your wild conjecture.

I've heard of "Econophysics" - a branch of physics that tries to use physics principles to predict financial markets.  However, this is a rather awesome attempt (and the first I've seen) at "Political Physics".  Awesome!

Comment: thanks for the response! @the_photon . I realize in practice it might be crazy, but I wonder if in some small systems it could be calculated. I suppose what I'm asking is: if you have a series of choices, can we assign a value to each choice that tells us not only its probability (say 0.5) but also what's upstream of it (say 0.15 summed probabilities). I suppose it would be sort of a Shannon measure upstream of choice x. Is there a name for this?